# Using select and values with insert into

Tags: sql, sql-insert, firebird

I'm writing a stored procedure.  I know how to pass values from `select` into `insert`.

But, is it possible with `INSERT INTO` to use `values` and `Select` at the same time?

```
Insert into table_1 (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9,
      FL1, FL2, FL3)

      Select :p_f1, :v_f2, :p_f3, :p_f4,
        abs(:v_f5 * :p_f5),
        abs(:v_f6 * :p_f6),
        :v_f7, :v_f8, :v_9 from RDB$DATABASE
      UNION
      Select f_lookup_id from lookup_table where (f_res >= :v_res) And (f2_lookup_id = :p_id1)
      UNION
      Select f_lookup_id from lookup_table where (f_res >= :v_res) And (f2_lookup_id = :p_id2)
      UNION
      Select f_lookup_id from lookup_table where (f_res >= :v_res) And (f2_lookup_id = :p_id3);
```

Comment: It's really tough to tell what you're asking here.  Can you show an example of what you're doing?  And your best guess at what you're trying to do?

Comment: can I use VALUES and Select with Insert into in one statement ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess you want to use the result set of a `SELECT` statement as a input of a `INSERT` statement? Yes, that's possible, see [FB's language reference](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-dml-insert). The part what probably causes your problem is that you don't use the `VALUES` keyword in that case, the statement would look like

```
INSERT INTO table (fields) SELECT ...
```

Or if you want to have both "constant values" (like in `INSERT INTO ... VALUES(...)` statement) and "dynamic values" (using `SELECT` statement as a source) in one statement then you can union them, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO table (fields)
     SELECT fields FROM tab_src ...
   UNION
     SELECT constants FROM RDB$DATABASE
```

where `constants` is list of values of appropriate type.

---

**UPDATE**

OK, I guess what you want is actually something like

```
Insert into table_1 (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9, FL1, FL2, FL3)
VALUES(:p_f1, :v_f2, :p_f3, :p_f4,
        abs(:v_f5 * :p_f5),
        abs(:v_f6 * :p_f6),
        :v_f7, :v_f8, :v_9,
        (Select f_lookup_id from lookup_table where (f_res >= :v_res) And (f2_lookup_id = :p_id1)),
        (Select f_lookup_id from lookup_table where (f_res >= :v_res) And (f2_lookup_id = :p_id2)),
        (Select f_lookup_id from lookup_table where (f_res >= :v_res) And (f2_lookup_id = :p_id3))
)
```

Comment: I am getting error: SQL error code = -104.
Invalid command.
count of column list and variable list do not match.
I wrote my SQL in generic field names above in main thread - Please advise. thanks

Comment: The error message `count of column list and variable list do not match` is pretty clear, isn't it? Your `INSERT` statement lists 12 columns and thus each "source row" must have 12 columns too, and the type of those columns must match the target column's type. But some of the `SELECT` statements you union only have one column! You can use NULL or some other (constant) default value instead of field name for those fields your source table doesn't have.

Comment: yes the msg is clear but I tried zeros in the first select only also RDB$DATABASE is something can not be concluded so thanks for the enlighten - I used zeros now like this: f_lookup_id,0,0  for first statement and 0, f_lookup_id, 0 and so on - but using UNION will not make zeros or null override real values ?

Comment: also using Union will return multi-rows but I need one row only I tried FIRST but still getting multi-rows

Comment: See the updated answer, the select statements must be singelton selects (return only one row).

Comment: BTW I still got multi-rows so I used First 1 is that correct ?

Comment: If youre sure taht the first record is the one you need then yes, nothing wrong with it.